# Discard all characters but the first 10 words before and after a search term

Tags: php, regex, full-text-search, preg-replace

I'm trying to finish the search function in one of the sites I'm developing. Since my search results only display excerpts of the contents of matched items, what I want to do is to highlight search terms within the search results and display only portions of texts that actually contain those search terms.

What I figured I'd do is to fetch the whole content from the database and use `preg_replace` to insert `<span>` elements around the search terms and at the same time extract only the first 10 words before and after the term. So this is the regex part of it:

```
(?:.*?)((?:\w+\W+){0,10})('.implode('|', $terms).')((?:\W*\w+\W+){0,10})
```

Basically, I try to "discard" all text except the first 10 words before the search term by using a non-capturing subpattern, then get the 10 words before the term, then the term itself, then the next 10 words.

This is the replacement text in `preg_replace`:

```
\\1<span class="search-term search-term-content">\\2</span>\\3...
```

The search term is being searched via the `MySQL`'s `MATCH()...AGAINST()` for `MyISAM FULLTEXT` indeces on multiple columns. However, the above regex is only being applied in one column (let's call this column, the one that uses the above regex, `content`).

So my problem is whenever I get a match on other columns but not on the `content` column, the regex above strips all text from the `content` column. That's because of the `(?:.*?)` subpattern at the very beginning which continues to match without ever finding the next subpatterns.

I was wondering if there was any other way to implement the original purpose of the regex without this side effect. I am currently thinking of simply using `preg_match_all` to just match the search term and 10 words before and after it. I'll just iterate over all of the matches and build the preview text manually. Yes, this is a sound solution but given my inexperience with regex, I thought I might as well try to find a solution to this.

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that I only get blank `contents` when I put 2 or more search terms. Other than that, it works perfectly. I now have no idea why this is happening.

**UPDATE 2**

Echo'ing `preg_last_error()`, I get this error `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR`. I use the words `new` and `post` for the search terms.

A `var_dump` of the regex and the terms show this:

```
@(?:.*?)((?:\w+\W+){0,10})(new|post)((?:\W*\w+\W+){0,10})@i

array
  0 => string 'new' (length=3)
  1 => string 'post' (length=4)
```

**UPDATE 3**

I used `Regex Coach` to walk me through the matching pattern, it seems that it backtracks too much after it finds no match for `(new|post)`. The target text is simply a random 3-paragraph lorem ipsum. I think I need to find a better regex for this task.

**UPDATE 4**

Using a `Once-Only` subpattern solves the problem. Though I have no idea of its details, I just re-read the PHP Manual and read a part of it that `Once-Only` subpatterns help with too much backtracking. This is the new regex:

```
(?:.*?)((?>\w+\W+){0,10})('.implode('|', $terms).')((?:\W*\w+\W+){0,10})
```

But I'm still open for suggestions for better regexes. Thanks!

Comment: What about when a search term occurs within 10 words after another search term? By this method you won't include the 10 words following that. Is that okay? What about when the search term occurs really frequently? Are you okay with this potentially returning the whole text? Seems like you might need a slightly more expensive approach to do this well...

Comment: Is the preg_replace returning an empty string or null? If it returns null then there's an error in your pattern, in which case you probably want to echo that out. First thought is that you need to preg_quote those values, unless you've already broken them down to alphanumeric characters only in the process of building the array.

Comment: Hi! I updated the question to state the error. I do agree that search terms too close to each other are a problem. Thanks for those comments! I don't mind it returning the whole text since I truncate the content before echo`ing it anyways.

Comment: Probably worth print_r-ing your terms array or echoing the pattern - it could be that you're getting '' or ' ' in there somehow

Comment: I used `Regex Coach` to walk me through the matching pattern, it seems that it backtracks infinitely after it finds no match for `(new|post)`. The target text is simply a random 3-paragraph lorem ipsum. The `var_dump` of the variables are in the edited question

Comment: Weird; I generated 150 paragraphs of lorem ipsum and it worked fine... Oh, and probably not your problem, but I think it should be `\W+\w+` after the terms, not `\W*\w+\W+`.

Comment: Hmmmm... This is the code: http://pastebin.com/dPvX3Jba. It's trimmed down to only include the relevant parts. The problem is in the regex.. It backtracks too much. I just have to think of a better regex, and keep in mind the points you said earlier. Actually, converting the *10-words before* subpattern `((?:\w+\W+){0,10})` to a `Once-Only` subpattern: `((?>\w+\W+){0,10})`, solves it. But still is inefficient, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having issues with hitting the backtracking limit, you generally want to look at [once-only subpatterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.onlyonce.php).

In this case however your main issue seems to be the `(?:.*?)` being followed by `(?:\w+\W+){0,10}`. Take for example the string 'hello world!', ignoring for now the `{0,10}`. This will match the two patterns as all of the following:

- '' and 'hello '
- 'h' and 'ello '
- 'he' and 'llo '
- 'hel' and 'lo '
- 'hell' and 'o '
- 'hello ' and 'world!'
- 'hello w' and 'orld!'
- 'hello wo' and 'rld!'
- 'hello wor' and 'ld!'
- 'hello worl' and 'd!'

The easiest way to block this redundant backtracking is to add a word boundary check (`\b`) after the `(?:.*?)` subpattern. This will reduce these potential matches to

- '' and 'hello '
- 'hello ' and 'world!'

**EDIT:** Here is an example of why a once-only subpattern will not work here:

```
preg_replace('/(?>[a-z]{0,2})a/','x','bac')
```

In this example we would expect the result 'xc', however the subpattern matches greedily to 'ba' and then never backtracks, thus missing the match. We could make the pattern ungreedy, but then we would get the result 'bxc', because it never backtracks after matching '' for the subpattern.

Comment: I see, so a `(?:.*?)\b((?:\w+\W+){0,10})('.implode('|', $terms).')((?:\W*\w+\W+){0,10})` would suffice for now? Any ideas if original problem can be solved via regex or should I parse the text manually?

Comment: Should work, or at least help, but yeah I would definitely go for parsing the text manually (well, using regexes, but in multiple stages) over a single-step approach. It is an interesting problem though... Personally I'd probably go about it by finding the position of each search term, working out ranges around them (measured in characters, not words), collapse any overlaps and then just output the first five or so ranges.